# Why I cannot update my heroku app via gitlab CI

Tags: django, heroku, gitlab

I have started messing around with Heroku docker and Django. I have followed the instructions of a tutorial and everything works great. My app is on Heroku, but I cannot update my App. According to the tutorial, when I push my new code to Gitlab the pipeline is run and it deploys the new code to my app in Heroku. Although the pipeline passes nothing changes on my Heroku app, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:stable
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  HEROKU_APP_NAME: myapp
  HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE: registry.heroku.com/${HEROKU_APP_NAME}/web

stages:
  - build_and_deploy

build_and_deploy:
  stage: build_and_deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - docker login -u _ -p $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN registry.heroku.com
    - docker pull $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE || true
    - docker build
        --cache-from $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
        --tag $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
        --file ./Dockerfile
        "."
    - docker push $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - chmod +x ./release.sh
```

And this is the release.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

IMAGE_ID=$(docker inspect ${HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE} --format={{.Id}})
PAYLOAD='{"updates": [{"type": "web", "docker_image": "'"$IMAGE_ID"'"}]}'

curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/"${HEROKU_APP_NAME}"/formation \
  -d "${PAYLOAD}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3.docker-releases" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

Last but not least here are the last messages of the pipeline, as I think that the rest of them are irrelevant to my question.

```
Successfully built dbd1d36dea04
Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/gollem/web:latest
$ docker push $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/gollem/web]
569b9f7da69f: Preparing
3dba57770497: Preparing
6f76eda67156: Preparing
ef56c01e8a45: Preparing
16542a8fc3be: Preparing
6597da2e2e52: Preparing
977183d4e999: Preparing
c8be1b8f4d60: Preparing
6597da2e2e52: Waiting
977183d4e999: Waiting
c8be1b8f4d60: Waiting
16542a8fc3be: Layer already exists
ef56c01e8a45: Layer already exists
6f76eda67156: Layer already exists
977183d4e999: Layer already exists
6597da2e2e52: Layer already exists
c8be1b8f4d60: Layer already exists
569b9f7da69f: Pushed
3dba57770497: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:df5aced032043ca4cfbe35c103a0bdbebab4460fee02b69d88541b96222b1e19 size: 1996
$ chmod +x ./release.sh
Running after_script
00:02
Saving cache
00:01
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
Job succeeded
```

**EDIT:**
It looks like gitlab-ci.yml never executed the release.sh script. So I added  `sh release.sh` at the end of the script.

```
image: docker:stable
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  HEROKU_APP_NAME: myapp
  HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE: registry.heroku.com/${HEROKU_APP_NAME}/web

stages:
  - build_and_deploy

build_and_deploy:
  stage: build_and_deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - docker login -u _ -p $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN registry.heroku.com
    - docker pull $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE || true
    - docker build
        --cache-from $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
        --tag $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
        --file ./Dockerfile
        "."
    - docker push $HEROKU_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - chmod +x ./release.sh
    - sh release.sh
```

Comment: which tutorial?

Comment: about:reader?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftestdriven.io%2Fblog%2Fdeploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker%2F

Answer (score 0):

when deploying via the Heroku Container Registry the workflow is normally the following:

```
docker build -t myImage .
docker tag myImage registry.heroku.com/appname/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/appname/web
heroku container:release web -a appname
```

I looked at the tutorial and indeed there are those steps (see Approach #1: Container Registry), in my example I tag the image after the build but the tutorial combines the 2 together.

Comment: Once I run, in PowerShell: 
```heroku container:release web -a appname```
I see all the changes that I commited. Should I place after chmod +x ./release.sh?

Comment: Uhm, I am not sure why you need/use the release.sh, I might miss something.. but in theory once you `release` the new version it should get deployed

Comment: the problem was that I never run the release.sh. I thought that chmod +x command made it an executable AND run it. Going to edit my question